# How to change permissions of /proc/pid/mem?

Tags: permissions

As a personal project, I'm writing a small tool in Haskell to mimic the functionality of [scanmem](https://github.com/scanmem/scanmem).

It

1. Scans /proc/pid/maps to obtain regions of virtual memory
2. Scans through /proc/pid/mem to extract regions of memory with a given value

It is still quite early in development, so I still rely a lot on cabal repl, which allows me to modify my code and then immediately go to an interactive ghci environment to run it. Unfortunately, since reading /proc/pid/mem requires sudo privileges, I need to run cabal repl as sudo. [This is heavily advised against](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/3353). I thought an alternative to having to build the entire code every time I make a minor change would be to change permissions to a specific/proc/pid/mem, so that any user can have read permission on this file. I would do all of my debuggin on this particular file.

Unfortunately, when I tried running

```
sudo chmod 644 mem
```

I got the result: `chmod: changing permissions of 'mem': Operation not permitted`

Is this idea just fruitless?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t change the permissions of `/proc/…/mem`, they are enforced by the kernel.

For your development work, you should be able to use any process your user is running; you’ll be able to access `/proc/…/mem` for processes running as your user. (`scanmem` can do this too — if you give it the pid of a process running as your user, it will analyse it without needing to be run as root). If you’re trying to scan all processes, skip those whose `mem` file is unreadable.